# Is there more than one occurrence of a power of two between twin primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

$2^2$ is between the twin primes $3$ and $5$.  Are there any other instances of a power of two between twin primes?  If so, how many?

That there are Mersenne primes (primes of the form $2^n-1$) makes this a little more tantalizing, but a brief search didn't spit out any results right away.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No: if $n$ is odd, $3\mid 2^n+1$, and if $n$ is even, $3\mid 2^n-1$.

To see this, note that $2^n+1=2^n+1^n$, which is divisible by $2+1$ if $n$ is odd, while $2^{2k}-1=4^k-1^k$ is divisible by $4-1$.

Comment: @Jedediyah: You’re welcome!

Comment: Alternatively, $2^n-1,2^n,2^n+1$ are three consecutive integers. One of them has to be divisible by $3$, and it can't be $2^n$.

Comment: @f'': True enough; sometimes the first workable idea that occurs to one isn’t the simplest idea!

Comment: Ah yes @f''!  I recognize that now.  I think I have seen this problem before but worded differently and did not make the connection until now  :)

Comment: I don't understand how it helps to look at $2^n + 1$ as $2^n + 1^n$, i.e. how it's more clear that way that it's divisible by $2 + 1$ if $n$ is odd. Same for the second case.

Comment: @Cedric: When $n$ is odd, $x^n+y^n$ factors as $$(x+y)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^ix^{n-1-i}y^i\;.$$

Comment: Hm, but e.g. for $x^3+y^3$ I get $(x+y)(x^2+xy+y^2) = x^3 + 2x^2y + 2xy^2 + y^3$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Cedric: You're missing the alternating sign: $$x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)\;.$$ That's why it works only for odd powers.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't there before, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

More complicatedly:

- If $2^n-1$ is a (Mersenne) prime, then $n$ must be prime: if $p|n$, then $2^p-1|2^n-1$.
- If $2^n+1$ is a (Fermat) prime, then $n$ must be a power of $2$: if $n=pk$ with $p$ odd, then $2^k+1|2^n+1$.

The only $n$ which is both prime and a power of $2$ is $2$ itself. So the only twin primes surrounding a power of $2$ will surround $2^2=4$.

Comment: Ohhhh I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Just some basics.  Twin primes use the last digits of 1 & 3, 7 & 9, and 9 & 1 5 is and exception to the general rule.  The powers of 2 use the last digits of 2, 4, 6, and 8.  The only valid powers of 2 will have the last digits of 2 and 8.  2^2 = 4 and 2^3 = 8.  Lots of luck trying to find more of them.